# SpringMvc doesn't handle exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

I defined the annotation @ExceptionHandler in my rest controller ,but it doesn't work as i wished when i mark the result type as text/plain,the method was defined to handle an attach upload request . SpringMvc just throw my business exception to the servlet container.Is it a bug of SpringMVC?How can i fix it?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController extends BasicController{
  @RequestMapping(value="/uploadAttach", headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"),method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="text/plain")
  public String test(){
   throw new ServiceException("biz exception");
  }
  @ExceptionHandler(value = {ServiceException.class})
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public @ResponseBody StatusMessage serviceError(ServiceException ex) {
    return new StatusMessage(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has interest to answer this problem,i have to solve it myself.
I found that the exception handler  will look for the right converter to handle the exception result which is defined as return value of the @ExceptionHandler. In my controller ,the exception is a pojo,when i debuged the program,i found there was no converter can write the pojo to type "text/plain" ,so SpringMvc throw the original exception to the servlet container,and returned an error page by Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

**you should follow these tips below:**

1.you should define a customized exception,
     but it must extend Exception.class;

2.setting a global exception hadler,and the dao throws the exception to service,the service throws to controller, then the controller uses the try...catch.. codes block to solve it;

3.a bean should be configured in SpringMVC.xml
like this:

4.and that's all, you can test it by using some simple codes like 1/0;